# how to empty a csv file before writing

Tags: python, csv

Hi I am trying to make a function which writes a table in a csv file.

But writerows and writerow just and an another table without clearing the first content(*unLike in txt files*)

here is the class and the program

```py
import csv as c

class Table:

    def __init__(self,File):
        self.file = File
        self.ro = c.reader(File)
        self.wo = c.writer(File)
        self.table_list = []
        for row in self.ro:
            self.table_list.append(row)

    def get_table_list(self):
        . . .

    def visualize_table(self):
        . . . 

    def get_number_of_column(self):
        . . .

    def get_number_of_row(self):
        . . .

    def get_index(self,item_entry,item):
        . . .
        
    def change(self,item_entry,item,to_item):
        . . .

    def write_table(self):
        self.wo.writerows(self.table_list)

file = open("test.csv","r+",newline="")

table = Table(file)

table.change("name","tarun","aditya")

table.write_table()

file.close()
```

before write_csv function
[image: befor write_csv]

after write_csv fuction
[image]

As you can see this is not what I want

please help me I cannot use any other module like pandas etc

Comment: You are better off with open-for-read/read/close when you want to read, and open-for-write/write/close when you want to write.  When using `'r+'` you have to seek to the beginning and truncate if you want to write an already open file, then seek to the beginning again if you want to read.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i read once and change the list which i write once so thank s

Comment: Don’t forget to seek(0,0). Null bytes don’t always display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the truncate method.

```
>>> file = open("test.csv","r+",newline="")
>>> file.truncate(0) # Clears file
```

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: @new_to_code `truncate` clears the file, but *does not* change the file position.  So then next write will occur at the same offset in the file, but everything before it will be reset to zero (at least on Windows).  Use `.seek(0,0)` and *then* `.truncate(0)`.

Comment: I did not look into that deeply. Thanks for pointing this out!